# Update multiple columns based on different rows in another column sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table

```
 staff   Type    col1   col2  
    1     a       0      200
    1     b       50     2000
    1     c       2      200
    2     a       0      100
    2     b       25     1000
    2     c       2      200
    3     a       0      150
    3     b       35     1500
    3     c       2      200
```

I am just wondering if I could update both `col1` and `col2` based on the values in the `Type` column for each staff. My logic to update would be for example for staff 1

update `col1` where `Type` =a is 200/(2000/50) =5
update `col1` where `Type` =b is `col1` - (200/(2000/50)) =50-5 = 45
update `col2` where `Type` =b is 2000-200 = 1800
update `col2` where `Type` =a to 0

Please see the resultant which I need to achieve is below and updated values(*)

```
staff   Type    col1   col2  
    1     a       5*      0*
    1     b       45*     1800*
    1     c       2      200
    2     a       2.5*    0*
    2     b       22.5*   900*
    2     c       2      200
    3     a       3.5*    0*
    3     b       31.5*   1350*
    3     c       2      200
```

Is it possible to get this done without using cursors/loops/functions/ctes?

Comment: Why do you divide by 50 for the 1st rule?

Comment: 50 is the value in col1 for the staff1 where type col=b. thats the formula i need to workout to calculate the value in col1 for the staff1 where type col=a

Comment: you want a single statement to update multiple columns with multiple different criteria?

Comment: yes thanks, sorry should have framed my question properly

Comment: So the col1 and col2 values only depend on staff and type - and nothing else?

Comment: yes only staff and type

Comment: Then I'd say drop those two columns and create a view instead. (Or have "calculated columns" instead (or what SQL Server calls those.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
    DECLARE @myTable TABLE (
  staff  INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Type   VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
  ,col1   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,col2   INTEGER  NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(1,'a',0,200),
 (1,'b',50,2000),
 (1,'c',2,200),
(2,'a',0,100),
(2,'b',25,1000),
(2,'c',2,200),
 (3,'a',0,150),
(3,'b',35,1500),
(3,'c',2,200)


UPDATE t1
SET Col1  = CASE WHEN Type ='a' 
            THEN col2/(Select Col2/Col1 FROM @myTable T2 WHERE T2.Type = 'b' AND T2.staff = T1.Staff)
            WHEN Type ='b'
            THEN col1 - ((Select Col2 FROM @myTable T2 WHERE T2.Type = 'a' AND T2.staff = T1.Staff)/(Col2/Col1))
            ELSE COl1
            END ,
    Col2 =  CASE WHEN Type = 'b'
            THEN Col2 - (Select Col2 FROM @myTable T2 WHERE T2.Type = 'a' AND T2.staff = T1.Staff)
            WHEN Type = 'a'
            THEN 0
            Else Col2
            END
FROM @MyTable t1

SELECT * FROM @myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one massive query, but you will likely need a lot of fail-safes to make it foolproof. For instance, you would've to account for a value of 0 in `b:col1` or `b:col2` (although assuming that you only want the cross multiplication, you can do `a:col2`*`b:col1`/`b:col2` and it's much simpler for the computer (divisions are a mess) on top of having 1 less exception. The drawback is when you start working with massive numbers, but I'm gonna assume that you won't go over 1000000^2 so that's kinda irrelevant. Similarly, my code is gonna assume that there is always exactly one `a` row and a `b` row.

```
declare @test as table(
    staff int,
    Type char(1),
    col1 decimal(6,2),
    col2 decimal(6,2)
)

insert into @test values(1,'a',0,200);
insert into @test values(1,'b',50,2000);
insert into @test values(1,'c',2,200);
insert into @test values(2,'a',0,100);
insert into @test values(2,'b',25,1000);
insert into @test values(2,'c',2,200);
insert into @test values(3,'a',0,150);
insert into @test values(3,'b',35,1500);
insert into @test values(3,'c',2,200);

UPDATE
    FirstTable
SET
    FirstTable.col1 = CASE FirstTable.[type] WHEN 'a' THEN JoinedTable.col1 * FirstTable.col2 / JoinedTable.col2 ELSE FirstTable.col1 - FirstTable.col1 * JoinedTable.col2 / FirstTable.col2 END,
    FirstTable.col2 = CASE FirstTable.[type] WHEN 'a' THEN 0 ELSE FirstTable.col2 - JoinedTable.col2 END
FROM
    @test FirstTable
INNER JOIN
    @test JoinedTable
ON
    FirstTable.staff = JoinedTable.staff AND JoinedTable.[Type] = CASE FirstTable.[Type] WHEN 'a' THEN 'b' ELSE 'a' END
WHERE
    FirstTable.[Type] in('a','b')
```

The behavior is as follow : if there is a 0 in a col2 for the Type `b`, it crashes. If there is more than one row for one staff with Type `a` or `b`, I believe it takes one of the 2 in a non deterministic fashion, which will lead to some non deterministic and potentially faulty results. If there is no Type `a` or `b`, it skips the staff entirely.

Otherwise (aka when it works), it simply updates rows with Type `a` and `b` based on their Type. Updating both in 1 query allow you to not use temporary tables and the likes since the new data doesn't override the old until the whole query is doen.

Also, try not to use keywords like `Type` for your columns or you may end up with some mistakes down the line.

Comment: Thanks for you answer!